# Why is hibernate.connection.release_mode after_transaction not recommended for JTA?

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, wildfly, jta

While analyzing some performance problems in Wildfly 10.1 in high pressure scenarios I came to the conclusion, that sometimes parallel HTTP threads block each other.

The reason seemed to be that in some HTTP requests we execute two JPQL Queries (actually a delete and a select) and sometimes the second of the two simply didn't get a JDBC connection from the pool. (We use IBM DB2, if that is important...) That seemed rather ridiculous as the first statement already got a connection.

After reading the Hibernate docs, I see that the default for `hibernate.connection.release_mode` is `after_statement` and that `after_transaction` is not recommended for JTA apps...

So... I have a few questions now:

- Why does `after_statement` ever make sense? (unless you have auto_comit on of course...)
- Why shouldn't I use `after_transaction` in JTA apps?
- Is my assumption correct that `after_transaction` should fix the described issue?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I am also looking at using release_mode after_transaction on wildfly but unsure.

Comment: Nope, looks like nobody understands this stuff :(

Comment: Have a look here: https://vladmihalcea.com/2015/12/22/hibernate-aggressive-connection-release/

Answer (score 5):

6 years later, but I hope this can help future readers.

### Background

For a couple of years, we have encountered a production bug that kept exhausting the pooled connection in an Atomikos managed Hibernate (3.x.x) & JTA integration.

With our Atomikos "recovery strategy" (i.e. force release all connections), this was fine until recent upscale with direct modern collaborators with multiple instances in K8S pushed the app's tipping point where we needed to address this issue.

Navigating around, I found the following set:

```java
setProperty("hibernate.connection.release_mode", "after_transaction");
```

Which after research it led me to this question (and other multiple unclear/unanswered questions regarding this mode)

So here are the findings:

### Origin of Flag

In 2005, it seems that a Hibernate JTA integration was causing issues, as a result [HHH-1287](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1287) was raised:

> It looks like the ExtendedJTATransaction is simply not available after the CMT completes and the WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup class attempts to look it up at java:comp/websphere/ExtendedJTATransaction as part of the normal 'after completion' callback.
>
> The problem occurs when the afterCompletion callback event fires and the ConnectionManager.isAggressiveRelease() method is called from ConnectionManager.afterTransaction(). This attempts to check to see if a transaction is in progress. This test in fact causes the transaction manager to be created (together with a look up of the current transaction) The lookup of the ExtendedJTATransaction fails and the an exception is thrown (see stack trace below).
>
> Although there may be an inconsistency in the way that a SSB and MDB operate, It seems fair to say that the transaction may not be available if it has completed. A workaround is therefore requested.

As a result a change was committed to circumvent the JTA transaction check in this scenario in the connection manager: (This has then gone though further improvements)

```java
private boolean isAggressiveReleaseNoTransactionCheck() {
    if (releaseMode == ConnectionReleaseMode.AFTER_STATEMENT) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        boolean inAutoCommitState;
        try {
            inAutoCommitState = isAutoCommit();
        }
        catch( SQLException e ) {
            inAutoCommitState=true; // assume we are in an auto-commit state
        }
        return releaseMode == ConnectionReleaseMode.AFTER_TRANSACTION && inAutoCommitState;
    }
}
```

### Feature Release

After verifying this works, it was released in the wild with the following documentation for 3.x.x:

**Table 3.4. Hibernate JDBC and Connection Properties**

| Property name | Purpose |
| --- | --- |
| hibernate.connection.release_mode | Specify when Hibernate should release JDBC connections. By default, a JDBC connection is held until the session is explicitly closed or disconnected. For an application server JTA datasource, you should use `after_statement` to aggressively release connections after every JDBC call. For a non-JTA connection, it often makes sense to release the connection at the end of each transaction, by using `after_transaction`. `auto` will choose `after_statement` for the JTA and CMT transaction strategies and `after_transaction` for the JDBC transaction strategy. **eg.** `auto` (default) / `on_close` / `after_transaction` / `after_statement` |

> For an application server JTA datasource, you should use `after_statement` to aggressively release connections after every JDBC call.

### Given conclusion

Therefore, this was work around certain containers (not just EE containers) that implement "resource containment" checks.

The Hibernate Session defers  getting a JDBC Connection until it actually needs one, which can lead to  cases like the following where 2 beans share a Session/EM:

- Bean1: get Session, but don't use it yet in way that needs Connection
- Bean1: call Bean2...
- Bean2: get Session, do some work forcing Session to obtain Connection
- Bean2: return (Session still hold Connection)

At this point, these containers see this as a "leaked" Connection because  the handle was not released by the end of the scope in which it was  obtained. Hence, aggressive releasing.

You can read more about this in detail here: [[hibernate-dev] - Connection release modes](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/hibernate-dev/2006-December/000903.html)

#### Useful References and Resources:

- [Hibernate - 11.5. Connection Release Modes](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/transactions-connection-release.html)
- [HHH-1287 - The issue that introduced the "after_statement" flag](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1287)
- ["after_transaction" vs "after_statement" - Hibernate Aggressive Connection Release](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-aggressive-connection-release/)

Answer (score 0):

Problems with connection pool management can occur at several levels, database, hibernate, application server. In order to facilitate this management, it is strongly recommended to use C3p0 which is a Java library that provides a convenient way for managing database connections.
See document [C3Po link](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-c3p0)

You can then configure in your hibernate.cfg.xml file the release mode of JTA transactions. It is best to leave it at the default value: "auto", as shown below:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</property><!-- Release mode database connection- auto the default value -->
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property> <!--  Number of prepared statements will be cached. 0 no caching -->
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">1000</property> <!-- Max connection pool size -->
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">50</property> <!-- Min connection pool size -->
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">550</property> <!-- Time in seconds before free a connection. 0 no expiration --> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod">1800</property> <!--  idle time in seconds before testing if a connection is valid - Setting a fairly long idleConnectionTestPeriod, and not testing on checkout and check-in at all is an excellent, high-performance approach. -->
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1;</property>
```