# com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosSQLException Connection pool exhausted - try increasing 'maxPoolSize' and/or 'borrowConnectionTimeout' on the DataSourceBean

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc, datasource, atomikos

We have an application that has faced such error after successfully doing bunch of transactions from db and we realized the jdbc connection pool is full of idle connections that won't be closed and keep piling up.

Here is the error log from springboot app:

```
2021-08-12T00:50:28,078 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap12FaultOutInterceptor:66] (http-nio-8080-exec-83) eventId=w:ef9c7df4-fae6-11eb-b2fa-000d3a434359, tenantId=, pe=, user=, app=, pid=, message=class org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap12FaultOutInterceptor$Soap12FaultOutInterceptorInternalmultipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; boundary="uuid:c21d3fc7-b321-4895-a608-1e4e58824a90"; start="<root.message@cxf.apache.org>"; start-info="application/soap+xml"
2021-08-12 00:51:28 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:137 [WARN] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2021-08-12 00:51:28 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:142 [ERROR] Connection pool exhausted - try increasing 'maxPoolSize' and/or 'borrowConnectionTimeout' on the DataSourceBean.
2021-08-12T00:51:28,074 WARN  [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain:475] (http-nio-8080-exec-84) eventId=w:e29c0214-fae6-11eb-8a27-000d3a434359, tenantId=, pe=, user=, app=, pid=, message=Interceptor for {urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007}HIEDirectXDRService#{urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007}DocumentRepository_ProvideAndRegisterDocumentSet-b has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [n/a]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:252) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateExceptionTranslator.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:102) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
......
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar!/:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar!/:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar!/:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar!/:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:134) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar!/:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:50) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar!/:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar!/:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar!/:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar!/:5.4.18.Final]
......
Caused by: com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosSQLException: Connection pool exhausted - try increasing 'maxPoolSize' and/or 'borrowConnectionTimeout' on the DataSourceBean.
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosSQLException.throwAtomikosSQLException(AtomikosSQLException.java:29) ~[transactions-jdbc-4.0.6.jar!/:?]
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean.throwAtomikosSQLException(AbstractDataSourceBean.java:76) ~[transactions-jdbc-4.0.6.jar!/:?]
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean.throwAtomikosSQLException(AbstractDataSourceBean.java:71) ~[transactions-jdbc-4.0.6.jar!/:?]
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean.getConnection(AbstractDataSourceBean.java:351) ~[transactions-jdbc-4.0.6.jar!/:?]
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.nonxa.AtomikosNonXADataSourceBean.getConnection(AtomikosNonXADataSourceBean.java:189) ~[transactions-jdbc-4.0.6.jar!/:?]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar!/:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar!/:5.4.18.Final]
......
```

We tried to increase maxpoolsize and borrowConnectionTimeout but haven't resolved the issue successfully. The app uses atomikos as transaction manager and we are trying to find how to close the idle connections after several minutes without any activities and keep the total number of connections down, fewer idle connections hanging out means more active connections can be going hopefully. We use XA transaction with atomikos. Please kindly advise how we could achieve the goal to keep idle connection down and close or flush the idle connection after certain time without active transaction to allow more active connections to start wtihout running out of the connection pool. Thanks. BTW, we use atomikos 4.0.6.

The application.yml looks like:

```
app:
  datasource:
    transaction:
      transaction_timeout: 600
    postgres:
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect
      driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    tac:
      borrow_conn_timeout: 30
      max_idle_time: 300
      min_pool_size: 5
      max_pool_size: 20
      show_sql: false
      max_lifetime: 1800
      test_query: 'select 1'
hibernate:
  connection:
    release_mode: after_transaction
  current_session_context_class: jta
spring:
  profiles:
    active: PostgreSql
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      use-new-id-generator-mappings: false
    properties:
      hibernate:
        id:
          new_generator_mappings: false
  jta:
    atomikos:
      connectionfactory:
        ignore-session-transacted-flag: false
        max-pool-size: 50
        min-pool-size: 5
      datasource:
        max-pool-size: 50
        min-pool-size: 5
      properties:
        service: com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceFactory
    enabled: true
```

Here is the DatabaseTransactionConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseTransactionConfiguration {

    @Value("${app.datasource.transaction.transaction_timeout}")
    Integer transactionTimeout = 300;

    @Bean(name = "userTransaction")
    public UserTransaction userTransaction() throws Throwable {
        final UserTransactionImp userTransactionImp = new UserTransactionImp();
        userTransactionImp.setTransactionTimeout(transactionTimeout);
        return userTransactionImp;
    }

    @Bean(name = "atomikosTransactionManager", initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
    public TransactionManager atomikosTransactionManager() throws Throwable {
        final UserTransactionManager userTransactionManager = new UserTransactionManager();
        userTransactionManager.setTransactionTimeout(transactionTimeout);
        userTransactionManager.setStartupTransactionService(false);
        userTransactionManager.setForceShutdown(false);
        return userTransactionManager;
    }

    @Bean(name = { "transactionManager", "jtaTransactionManager" })
    @DependsOn({ "userTransaction", "atomikosTransactionManager" })
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws Throwable {
        final UserTransaction userTransaction = userTransaction();
        final TransactionManager atomikosTransactionManager = atomikosTransactionManager();
        return new JtaTransactionManager(userTransaction, atomikosTransactionManager);
    }
}
```

Here is the DataSourceConfigurationTAC.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataSourceConfigurationTAC {

    @Value("${app.datasource.postgres.driverClassName}")
    String postgresDriverClass;

    @Value("${app.datasource.oracle.dialect}")
    String oracleDialect;

    @Value("${app.datasource.postgres.dialect}")
    String postgresDialect;
    
    @Value("${app.datasource.danc.borrow_conn_timeout}")
    Integer borrowConnectionTimeout;
    
    @Value("${app.datasource.danc.max_idle_time}")
    Integer maxIdleTime;
    
    @Value("${app.datasource.danc.min_pool_size}")
    Integer minPoolSize;
    
    @Value("${app.datasource.danc.max_pool_size}")
    Integer maxPoolSize;
    
    /**
     * Maximum amount of seconds that a connection is kept in the pool before 
     * it is destroyed automatically. Optional, defaults to 0 (no limit).
     */
    @Value("${app.datasource.tac.max_lifetime:0}")
    Integer maxLifetime;
    
    /**
     * SQL query or statement used to validate a connection before returning it. Optional.
     */
    @Value("${app.datasource.tac.test_query:@null}")
    String testQuery;

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @Primary
    public DataSource tacDataSource() throws SQLException {
        AtomikosNonXADataSourceBean bean = new AtomikosNonXADataSourceBean();
        bean.setUniqueResourceName(dataSourceName);
        bean.setDriverClassName(OdxcEnvironment.isPostgreSql() ? postgresDriverClass : oracleDriverClass);
        bean.setBorrowConnectionTimeout(borrowConnectionTimeout);
        bean.setMaxIdleTime(maxIdleTime);
        bean.setMinPoolSize(minPoolSize);
        bean.setMaxPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
        bean.setMaxLifetime(maxLifetime);
        bean.setTestQuery(testQuery);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean(name = { "sessionFactory" })
    @Primary
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean customerEntityManager(
            @Autowired @Qualifier("jtaTransactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
            @Autowired @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource tacDataSource) throws Throwable {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(tacDataSource);

        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", postgresDialect);
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.transaction.jta.platform", AtomikosJtaPlatform.class.getName());
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("javax.persistence.transactionType", "JTA");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class", "jta");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary", Boolean.FALSE.toString());
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", Boolean.FALSE.toString());
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", Boolean.FALSE.toString());
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", Boolean.FALSE.toString());
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments", Boolean.FALSE.toString());
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size", "16");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class",
                "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region_prefix", "connnectivity_springboot");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", Boolean.FALSE.toString());
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
        sessionFactoryBean.setJtaTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope anyone who has such experience could help me. Thanks so much. Appreciate that!

Comment: Please let me know if you need more information on how we have this issue either from code or from configuration. Thanks. It is the issue across board which really stretches us a lot.

Comment: Does anyone know how to configure datasource correctly to let atomikos close the idle connections not piling up the connection pool?

Answer (score 0):

Very late, however, I can see a potential problem here that could leak your connections. You're setting your hibernate connection mode to `after_transaction`, whereas for a JTA datasource you should set it to `after_statement`.

**Table 3.4. Hibernate JDBC and Connection Properties**

| Property name | Purpose |
| --- | --- |
| hibernate.connection.release_mode | Specify when Hibernate should release JDBC connections. By default, a JDBC connection is held until the session is explicitly closed or disconnected. For an application server JTA datasource, you should use `after_statement` to aggressively release connections after every JDBC call. For a non-JTA connection, it often makes sense to release the connection at the end of each transaction, by using `after_transaction`. `auto` will choose `after_statement` for the JTA and CMT transaction strategies and `after_transaction` for the JDBC transaction strategy. **eg.** `auto` (default) / `on_close` / `after_transaction` / `after_statement` |

> For an application server JTA datasource, you should use `after_statement` to aggressively release connections after every JDBC call.

You can see more details here: [Why is hibernate.connection.release_mode after_transaction not recommended for JTA?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75628478/5037430)